# Topographic type of map on routeme in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, openstreetmap, topography

I have integrated offline maps into my project with the help of route-me sample app (https://github.com/route-me/route-me). But my client wants to show topographical type of map as the open street map. I have searched over the internet, couldn't find any helpful resources.

- Do you know any resources I should follow to implement this feature?
- Should I have to use another way of implement the Open Street Maps in
  order to get the topographic type of map?

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe have a look at [mapbox.com](http://www.mapbox.com) and their map tool (TileMill) which allow you to add and customize your own layers.

As for the topographic data needed to create your layers, you should be able to find some on websites like http://www.naturalearthdata.com/.

Comment: Thanks Kirualex...I will look into that:) But I found out that OSM does not have in-built feature to support topographic data, so instead client agreed to display cycle type of map (in-build feature in OSM) which is bit similar to topographic type of map.